# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() line 161 , Undefined variable line 166.167.168

Tags: php, foreach, undefined

```
<?php 
  //Conexion base de datos 
  $servidor ="localhost";
  $usuario ="t";
  $password ="";    
  $bd ="cromop";
  $mysql = new mysqli($servidor , $usuario , $password , $bd );
  $mysql->set_charset("utf8");

  //Termina conexion base de datos

?>
<?php
  if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }
      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
    return $theValue;
  }
}

$busqueda = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['busqueda'])) {
  $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda']; 
}
// Definición del buscador
$busqueda = $mysql->query ("SELECT distinct Nombre, Apodo, aux1  FROM 
 jugadores3 WHERE Apodo LIKE _utf8 %s COLLATE utf8_general_ci order by Apodo ASC ");
// Colecciones Este
$este = $mysql->query ("SELECT distinct Temporada FROM cromoseste ORDER BY rand() limit 3");
// Colecciones MC
$mc = $mysql->query ("SELECT distinct Temporada FROM cromosmc ORDER BY rand() limit 3");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <!-- Logo -->
  <h1><a href="#" id="logo">Cromopedia</a></h1>
  <!-- Nav -->
  <nav id="nav">
    <a href="index.php">Inicio</a>
    <a href="jugadores.php">Jugadores</a>
    <a href="entrenadores.php">Entrenadores</a>
    <a href="equipo.php">Equipos</a>
    <a href="editorial.php">Editoriales</a>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>
</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="3u">
          <!-- Left Sidebar -->
          <section>
            <header>
              <h2>Colecciones Este</h2>
            </header>
            <ul class="link-list">
              <?php foreach ($este as $r)?>
              <center><a href=temporadaseste.php?temporada=<?php echo ($r['Temporada']); ?>><img src="images/banner/este/<?php echo $r['Temporada']; ?>.jpg" width="90" height="115" /></br><?php echo $r['Temporada']; ?></a></center>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <header>
              <h2>Mundicromo</h2>
            </header>
            <ul class="link-list">
              <?php foreach ($mc as $m)?>
                <center><a href=temporadasmc.php?temporada=<?php echo ($m['Temporada']); ?>><img src="images/banner/mc/<?php echo $m['Temporada']; ?>.jpg" width="90" height="115" /></br><?php echo $m['Temporada']; ?></a>
                </center>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="6u skel-cell-important">
          <!-- Main Content -->
          <section>
            <header>
              <h2>Encontrastes:</h2>
            </header>
            <?php foreach ($busqueda as $b ) ?>
              {
              <table width="100%" align="center" frame="void" class="tabla">
                <tr>
                  <th><center>Apodo</center></th>
                  <th><center>Nombre</center></th>
                  <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a href=player.php?aux1=<?php echo ($b['aux1']); ?>><?php echo $b['Apodo'];?></a></td>
                  <td><a href=player.php?aux1=<?php echo ($b['aux1']); ?>><?php echo $b['Nombre'];?></a></td>
                  <td><a href=player.php?aux1=<?php echo ($b['aux1']); ?>><img src="images/jugadores/<?php echo $b['aux1']; ?>.jpg" width="65" height="106" /> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              }
            </section>
```

Comment: Añade las llaves { y } para el foreach. También sería útil tener la parte del código en donde se define $busqueda.

Comment: @track3r he probado lo que me comentas y no ha surgido efecto. Te puse la definición de la busqued..Saludos

Comment: Parece que faltan partes y las que hay están mal, por ejemplo, en la cadena SQL aparece %s cuando esto se utiliza junto con sprintf pero no lo usas. A parte de que el código está lleno de errores y está poco legible, ¿puedes editar la pregunta y colocar el código limpio y completo de la parte en dónde está el problema?

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es un var_dump de $busqueda para ver qué contiene, porque yo creo que es que no tiene nada.

Comment: Te comento el problema es que mi web está hecha con el script del dreamweaver en php 6 y la estoy actualizando a php 7 con lo poco que se. Por eso el codigo lo ves como lo ves por que lo estoy modificando y me salen errores.

Comment: Entiendo, nuestro problema es que el código que nos enseñas no es suficiente para dar con el problema. Mira a ver si puedes copiar el código y no el resultado con errores. Nos sería de utilidad.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta y puse el código de la pagina.Esto es el resultado de un buscador en base datos al que por url le llega una variable.Gracias por intentar ayudarme

Comment: He reformateado el código para dar más claridad y sin profundizar mucho, tienes muchos errores, por ejemplo, en el tercer foreach, abres { y cierras } fuera de los que serían los tags de PHP, por lo que no funcionará. También asignas en $busqueda un GET pero luego reasignas en $busqueda una conexión con lo que pierdes el valor anterior, además, en la cadena SQL usas %s sin sprintf por lo que no funcionará. Hay demasiados errores como para que funcione algo, te recomiendo reducir las partes al mínimo y probarlas por separado para luego integrarlas cuando sepas que funcionan.

Comment: Además, no formulas ninguna pregunta y se espera que lo que se publique aquí, sea en forma de pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

tu problemas es que no obtienes los resultados solo ejecutas la query debes usar
 `$resultado->fetch_assoc()` tambien te recomiendo cambiar `foreach` por `while`

**ejemplo:**

```
while ($r = $este->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo $r['Temporada'];
}
```